# Why my variable is Nil? - Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a controller called Produto and a model called Produto. I want to pass all the Produto objects to a variable as the same the Produto controller does, but to another controller. So, the controller Produto take @Produto = Produto.all in her Index def and the view of this controller uses that variable. But i want to do this in other controller.
Look what i have :

Produto controller:

```
class ProdutosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_produto, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /produtos
  # GET /produtos.json
  def index
    @produtos = Produto.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @produto = Produto.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @produto = Produto.new(produto_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @produto.save
        format.html { redirect_to @produto, notice: 'Produto was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @produto }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @produto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @produto.update(produto_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @produto, notice: 'Produto was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @produto }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @produto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @produto.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to produtos_url, notice: 'Produto was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_produto
      @produto = Produto.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def produto_params
      params.require(:produto).permit(:nome, :preco, :fornecedor_id)
    end
end
```

Home controller (this is the controller i want to take those Produto objects too, as the same the Produto controller):

```
    class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @produtos = Produto.all
    render "index"
  end

  def show
    if session[:user]
      @user = User.find(session[:user])
    end
  end

end
```

the view of Home has this part on the code:

```
  <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Preco</th>
      <th>Fornecedor</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <% @produtos.each do |produto| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= produto.nome %></td>
          <td><%= produto.preco %></td>
          <td><%= produto.fornecedor %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Show', produto %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_produto_path(produto) %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', produto, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**and i'm getting this error**:

> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass in <% @produtos.each do
>   |produto| %>

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'login#new'
  get 'home#index'

  scope '/login' do
    get '/acesso', to:'login#new'
    post '/acessorecebendo', to:'login#create'
    get '/sair', to:'login#destroy'
  end

  resources :login
  resources :home
  resources :produtos
  resources :fornecedors
end
```

Login controller (which is the root route):

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def new
    if session[:user]
      @user = User.find(session[:user])
    end
  end

  def destroy
    reset_session
    redirect_to "/login/acesso", notice: "Você foi deslogado"
  end


  def create
    user = User.validate(login_params[:email], login_params[:senha])
    if user
      session[:user] = user.id
      redirect_to "/home/index", notice: "login feito com sucesso"
    else
      redirect_to "/login/acesso", notice: "Dados incorretos"
    end

  end
  private
  def login_params
    params.require(:login).permit(:email, :senha)
  end
end
```

Comment: In which view is `@produtos.each`?

Comment: A view called inicio.html.erb which is a view from the Home controller

Comment: So you need to create the variable `@produtos` there, this way is available in the view which responds to that method.

Comment: It is! 

  def inicio
    @produtos = Produto.all
    render "inicio"
  end
end

Comment: `inicio` in the `HomeController`?

Comment: Yes, def inicio doesnt exist anymore but this is the def index at HomeController:

`class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @produtos = Produto.all
    render "inicio"
  end

  def show
    if session[:user]
      @user = User.find(session[:user])
    end
  end

end`

Comment: @MikhaelAraujo Its better to update (edit) your question.

Comment: @Gerry did this right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your routes, methods, views match:

```
# config/routes.rb
get '/home/inicio', to: 'home#index'

# app/controllers/home_controller.rb
def index
  @produtos = Produto.all
end

# app/views/home/index.html.erb
<% @produtos.each do |produto| %>
```

As you see it changes just the URI but you must make reference to your `index` method in both controller method and view name.

If you use `render 'inicio'` then you must use the `inicio.html.erb` view instead `index.html.erb`.

Comment: It's probably `home_controller.rb`

Comment: def index
    @produtos = Produto.all
  end

the Variable already assigned on the Home Controller.

Comment: Try changing the route from `post` to `get` -> `get 'home#inicio'`, and making reference to the method with "#".

Comment: getting this error after that change:

check_part': Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes. (ArgumentError)

Comment: @MikhaelAraujo Double check your view/action names: either change the view name to `index.html.erb` or change the action name to `inicio` (as stated in the answer).

Comment: i've changed the view of Home to index but still getting this error lol

Comment: YEAH! my project its alive! haha. ty u so much !

Comment: You're welcome, just keep in mind such "rule". Thank all.